# Выполнение метода в определенное время

Tags: c#, wpf

Необходимо выполнять метод в определенное время.

Единственный вариант который я вижу - таймер на 1 минуту с проверкой времени.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может есть более гуманный вариант?

**UPD:**
Время произвольное.

Comment: Незачем раз в минуту. Можно первым интервалом прыгнуть почти ко времени выполнения. Но и это не поможет, если программа закроется, а поэтому нужно смотреть в сторону планировщика в оси

Comment: @vitidev, нет, будем учитывать то, что программа будет работать в указанное время. Можно по подробнее как "прыгнуть почти ко времени выполнения"?

Comment: Ну если запланировано через час, то незачем 59 раз проверять не наступило ли время, а поставить таймер на (нужное время минус текущее) или на 59 минут и потом мелкими шажками если к таймеру есть недоверие (вообще то таймеры работают хорошо, но они планируют калбек в пуле потоков и надо его не занимать)

Comment: @vitidev, время произвольное.

Comment: Ну если планировщик (таймер) не знает на момент планирования итоговое время старта, то можно и в лоб - проверять через интервал "нет ли какой задачи", а можно сделать так чтобы тот, кто выставлял  (если возможно) время и запускал таймер. То есть либо тот кто выставляет конечное время сам и планирует, либо планировщик периодически проверяет. Других вариантов в принципе быть не может.

Comment: Если лень писать свой планировщик, возьмите Quarz.net, довольно мощная штука. Таймер раз раз в минуту вполне гуманный вариант, минута это очень долго, но если погрешность в минуту устраивает, то можно и раз в минуту.